# how to know if our org. has sent more than a 1000 emails on a specific date

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, governorlimits

I am working on a requirement and needs to know how to know if our org. has sent more than a 1000 emails on a specific date.

I have found the following code :

```
System.debug('limits.getEmailInvocations()                 = ' + limits.getEmailInvocations());
System.debug('limits.getLimitEmailInvocations()            = ' + limits.getLimitEmailInvocations());
```

found from https://gist.github.com/tyoshikawa1106/e28b602f82582cf119ae

But they can't be used for a specific date. is there any other way using workbench etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to get that information programmatically. The Limits class only tells you the usage for the current transaction, not for the entire day. You can use the setup menu to request an email log file, but this is run asynchronously.

Comment: So there is no way to get email sent on a specific date using soql/ API.

Comment: @cloudlover If you're just concerned about if you're going to hit the limit, you can use [reserve*EmailCapacity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm) functions before you try to send the emails.